# Stanford nlp document preprocessor adding the space between the words which is not required

Tags: c#

"The issuer cannot be recommended to make payment by another shouldnot issuer. This is for testing of spaces."

This is the sample text. when I pass to stanford nlp document preprocessor for breaking the paragraph into sentences. Am getting sentences with extra space added to the word ***cannot*** in the text. i.e

***Present output***

The issuer ***can not*** be recommended to make payment by another shouldnot issuer.

***Expected output***

The issuer ***cannot*** be recommended to make payment by another shouldnot issuer.

```
DocumentPreprocessor docPre = new DocumentPreprocessor(new java.io.StringReader(textChunk));

        foreach (java.util.ArrayList sentenceArray in docPre)
        {
            string sentence = "";
            foreach (CoreLabel word in sentenceArray)
            {
                sentence += word + " ";

            }}
```

DocumentPreprocessor docPre = new DocumentPreprocessor(new java.io.StringReader(textChunk));

The above line is dividing the word cannot into  can not. Not sure of the reason. Is there any way where i can eliminate of this unnecessary space which is getting added.
Thanks in advance.

[image]
This is the textchunk.

[image]

Comment: can you debug and show textchunk? cos that would suggest can and not were indeed separate

Comment: The above screeshot contains textChunk. where "cannot" is a single word. Thank you

Comment: shouldnot isnt one word in the english language btw. I can agree here it doesnt look like 2 words.

Comment: In the newly added screen shot, we see that [2]can [3]not as two different words. [11]shouldnot as single word. The textChunk contains "shouldnot" as single word, so it is fine. But the textChunk contains "cannot" as single word, but document preprocessor is dividing it as "can" and "not". When it does not add space for "shouldnot" it should not obviously add for "cannot" as well

Comment: Dont know the actual reason for this. So not able to find the solution too in a generic way

Comment: maybe its splitting them because cannot is poor english and can not, and can't are the expected variations?

Comment: Adding space, I mean the document preprocessor is dividing the words which in original text are of single word. Specifically word "CANNOT". I hope am more clear now. Thank you

Comment: but just as word would turn "teh" to the if you let auto correct, perhaps this is doing something similar.. clearly whatever, it is out of your control, unless there are options

Comment: Yaeh may be. But am really not sure. Thank you.

Comment: Yaeh. You are right. But this is creating a great issue for my further functions which depends on this. Seems it is doing only for CANNOT. Thanks for your patience and explaination